# How to generate client secret key with timestamp using .pem file in c#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have .pem file provided by client and using this file I have to generate client_secret key using below points -

1.The service account has the public key from a public-private key pair provided 
  by the client.

2.The time stamp is formatted as a decimal string indicating the time in 
   milliseconds after January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

3.The time stamp is then signed/encrypted using the private key of the service 
   account associated with the client and Base 64 encoded.

I have implemented code as per above requirement but web API server return below error -

**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Unable to authenticate. [ clientId: "my key" ]."}.**

Here is my function to generate client_secret key -

```
    private string getsecretkey()
   {
           string privateKeyPath = @"C:\Users\vijay.birari.DGSL\Desktop\Temp\familysearchserviceaccount1.PEM";
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(privateKeyPath);
           PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr);
           AsymmetricCipherKeyPair KeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();
           RSAParameters rsa = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)KeyPair.Private);

           //RsaKeyParameters publickey = (RsaKeyParameters)KeyPair.Public;
           RsaKeyParameters privatekey = (RsaKeyParameters)KeyPair.Private;

           // Timestamps code
           TimeSpan ts = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
           long millis = (long)ts.TotalMilliseconds;
           string sTimestamp = Convert.ToString(millis);
           byte[] Timstamp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sTimestamp);

           IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
           cipher.Init(true, privatekey);
           byte[] bytesTimestampUtf8Encrypted = cipher.ProcessBlock(Timstamp, 0, Timstamp.Length);
           string encode = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesTimestampUtf8Encrypted);
           string secret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encode, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);

           return secret;

  }
```

---

calling above function in the below code -

string respones = string.Empty;

```
 try
        {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://ident.familysearch.org/cis-web/oauth2/v3/token?");
       sb.Append("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=");
       sb.Append(client_id);
       sb.Append("&client_secret=");
       // sb.Append("=");
       sb.Append(getsecretkey());
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
           request.Method = "POST";
           // request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
          // request.ContentType = "application/json";
           using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
           {


               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    respones = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(respones))
                {
                    dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respones.ToString());
                    dynamic data = JObject.Parse(respones);
                    respones = data.access_token;
                }

               }
               return webresponse;

           }

            }
        catch (WebException wex)
       {
           if (wex.Response != null)
           {
               using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response)
               {
                   using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                   {
                       respones = reader.ReadToEnd();
                       //TODO: use JSON.net to parse this string and look at the error message
                   }
               }
           }

           return respones;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved my problem.
I have replaced OaepEncoding() with the Pkcs1Encoding().

e.g. - IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());